# WiX: Uninstall is not stopping or removing my windows service

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am new to WiX but I have done some stuff with Installshield and the Windows Installer in the past.

I have what I think is a fairly simple installer that sets up a windows service.  It sets it up under the "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" if that makes a difference.

Install works fine, but during uninstall I get a prompt telling me this "The setup must update files or services that cannot be updated when the system is running.  If you choose to continue, a reboot will be required to complete the setup.".  If I click okay everything is uninstalled except the service (even after a reboot).  It is still started and the exe associated with the service is left behind too.

I can manually stop and remove the service without a problem with the sc.exe command.

Also if I had the service manually stopped before I run the uninstall I do not get the above mentioned prompt but the result is still the same.  The service is left and so is the file.

Here is part of my Wix:

```
<Component Id='cmpService' Guid='{542f970e-ca39-4501-aae4-9e03eaac9a25}' >
    <File Id='ServiceExeFile' Name='nls.service.agent.exe'
            ReadOnly='no' Compressed='yes' KeyPath='yes' Vital='yes' Hidden='no' System='no'
            Checksum='no'  />
    <ServiceInstall Id='MyServiceInstall' DisplayName='RaMP Data Collector' Name='rampDataCollector'
            ErrorControl='normal' Start='auto' Type='ownProcess' Vital='yes'
            Account='NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' />
    <ServiceControl Id='MyServiceControl' Name='rampDataCollector'  
            Start='install' Stop='uninstall' Remove='uninstall' Wait='yes' />
</Component>
```

I have tried

- Taking off Account='NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' and got the same result
- Changing all my Guids just be sure and got the same result.
- Look at a verbose log for both scenarios (service running before uninstall and stopped before uninstall) but I didn't see anything interesting that I could decipher.

Here are pieces from the msi log from when I run the uninstall and the service is manually stopped first.  I pasted the parts around the service component and MSI actions.

```
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:080]: Component: cmpService; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:080]: Component: cmpFolderPermissions; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:080]: Component: cmpApplicationShortcut; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent
```

AND

```
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:876]: Doing action: StopServices
Action ended 10:44:11: SchedSecureObjectsRollback. Return value 1.
Action start 10:44:11: StopServices.
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:878]: Doing action: DeleteServices
Action ended 10:44:11: StopServices. Return value 1.
Action start 10:44:11: DeleteServices.
MSI (s) (A4:58) [10:44:11:879]: Doing action: RemoveRegistryValues
Action ended 10:44:11: DeleteServices. Return value 1.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I guess as a last resort I could do a custom action and stop/remove the service at uninstall using the sc command.

Comment: Upon some further testing.  I think it might be something "odd" with the exe.  If I have the same install set up a service with a simple test exe it installs and uninstalls fine.

I am not really sure what could be odd about the exe.  I will have to talk to the Developers who authored id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that the service commands don't occur when the installer is uninstalled but when the component is uninstalled.  As the log says, no action is being taken.

This can happen if you do things like break the component rules or service the application outside of the installer and mess up component/file reference counts.

For example, if foo.exe existed and then MSI installed foo.exe, it would get left behind on uninstall.  Therefore the service associated with it would also.

Comment: Hm.  I think you have a very valid point.

I am trying to see how they may help me find what must have gone wrong.  I decided to try to install the service disabled AND make sure that the exe was not there from some previously un-clean uninstall.  The result was slightly different.  The EXE was removed but the service was still left behind.  The log still said "Component: cmpService; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null"

Comment: I am not sure how I would be messing with the service to keep it from uninstalling but I must be.  Any other thoughts or examples on how I be messing up the component rules?  Should I have the exe's required dll's in the same component?

Comment: I'd have to look at the log to know more.  One question though,  how are you testing this?  On a clean virtual machine with snapshots to roll back to a known state or a physical machine that's possibly dirty from previous development?

Comment: The component rules dictate that each DLL/EXE must be the key file of it's own component.  There is an edge case exception with regard to certain publishing to the GAC situations but that's not the case here.

Comment: I made a mistake earlier when I said the exe was being removed.  I had forgotten that I added a removeFile tag to my wix to remove all files (*.*) at uninstall.

Comment: I am testing it on my dev machine.  I agree that it would be better to do this on a clean virtual.  What you said about dll/exe and components is what I thought and how I have it (basically one file per component).

Comment: You need to retest on a clean machine and I suspect you'll find it's actually working.   The only way to get it to work on your dirty dev machine will be to go through the registry and clean up all the component and file references count to get back to that clean state.  Then it'll work on your dev machine.  But remember, you should never, ever be testing installers on your Dev machine until they are mature and have gone through extensive QA testing.

Comment: You make a good point.  I will do a clean test in the office on monday.  In case you want to glance at my log file I put it here [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11XtL0udxwQzyYhPUN2PaBc7518KlAj4Gu1DzWmhMTMI/edit)  I wasn't really sure what was the best way to share a file here.

Comment: I would need more verbosity on that log. msiexec /x foo.msi /l*v uninstall.log   ( l*v is verbose )

Comment: Sorry about the verbosity of the log.  I must have neglected the *v.

Well as usual it is the most obvious solution turns out right.  I tested on a clean virtual today and it worked fine every time.  I feel stupid for not doing it sooner.  Thanks Christopher!